# Search and navigation in SPA

Tags: javascript, react-router, single-page-application

I'd like users to bookmark or copy/paste their current search so that they can search with the same parameters.

- I'm using GET parameters for search params
- I'm pushing the url in the navigation history

Problem is this:

Suppose a user search with param1 then search with param2. 
When he hits back-button, he won't see results with param1.

That's because we send the GET request via ajax and update the ui with javascript without page refresh.

If you want to show the correct previous search results, I guess

- I can either save the search results itself in a stack (I guess it will be too expensive
- or I can save the search params in the stack with the pushed url, and re do the search either through network or offline if possible.

I guess this kind of problem could occur in many areas in SPA not just with search.

I wonder how people address this problem and if there's a well accepted solution, be it a strategy or a library..

I'm using react, react-router, redux.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add the search string to your url with hash tag?

```
window.location.hash = 'SEARCH_1';
```

I am not sure if that works for your need, but you can add this code in the success callback of your search function. And it will enable the user with the browser back button.

And in your componentDidMount(), you will need to check if the hash tag is null or not. If it is not null, you need to call search function to retrieve the result when the component finishes loading.